# SCJD synchronized statement vs Lock

Tags: java

I'm trying to justify the use of `synchronized` statement vs Java Concurrent API for my SCJD.

So far the only reason I can give is it is more simple, easier to understand and cleaner.

Are there any better technical reasons?

Answer (score 2):

The best reason is robustness.

A lock must be released, and forgetting to do it, or not doing it properly (in a finally block) can have disastrous effects.

Since synchronized protects a whole block of code or a method, and automatically releases the lock when the block or method ends, using it is safer and leads to less programming errors.